# How to launch the Stanford CoreNLP server for a remote access (not localhost) under Windows 10

Tags: stanford-nlp

The server runs well in local mode: I can correctly have the Stanford CoreNLP web page under localhost:9000 or 192.168.1.nn:9000.

Unfortunately when I call the web page from another computer's (on the LAN) (I call 192.168.nn.nn:9000), I have a ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT error in the internet browser. I note that the port is not reachable (via telnet).

How can I launch the StanfordCoreNLP server so that it can be acceeded remotely (on a Windows 10 platform)?

The command line is:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

The output is:

```
[main] INFO CoreNLP - --- StanfordCoreNLPServer#main() called ---
[main] INFO CoreNLP - setting default constituency parser
[main] INFO CoreNLP - warning: cannot find edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
[main] INFO CoreNLP - using: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz instead
[main] INFO CoreNLP - to use shift reduce parser download English models jar from:
[main] INFO CoreNLP - http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
[main] INFO CoreNLP -     Threads: 4
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting server...
[main] INFO CoreNLP - StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
```

It launches also well with variants such as:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -serverProperties _myStanfordServerCoreNLP-french.properties -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

Would there be some server properties to define, but which ones (I hardly find online doc on it)?

Many thanks for your help.

L.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that applying the latest Windows 10 update, followed by a reboot has resolved the issue.

So I understand that no specific setting is needed to share the server over the LAN.

L.